# Highlight fields in InfoPath that have changed

Tags: infopath, highlighting

I am able to highlight fields in InfoPath if they are "new" by setting the conditional formatting to "set this field to yellow if the value is not blank"

What I'm trying to do though is highlight fields when the value is changed.  That is, when the value it pulled from the webservice is not the current value of the field.

The forms in question have a large number of fields.  So  I would prefer not to use some sort of flag field for each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done so far, for non-repeating fields, I've added a "flag field" for each non-repeating field.
Then set a rule on the field that when it's been changed to set the flag field to "true" and set conditional formatting on the field that if the flag field is "true" then set the background to yellow.

This works, but requires a flag field for each field on the form.
Haven't figured out how to do repeating fields yet.

---

Did figure out repeating fields.

We've added a field called IsDirty to the data source object that repeats. then followed the same process in the repeating sections, on the field set a rule that when the value's changedthe isdirty is set to true.  Then a conditional formatting that if Isdirty==true, se the field's background to yellow.